# Reusing jQuery dialog box the title bar is on the screen after close

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery  dialog box on user control which is menu bar and location every page. The pop-up dialog is works fine without problem. Now on the page "Order.aspx" that has another user control in which a button open the "Detail.aspx" in dialog box. The dialog box can open, however when it close, the title bar is still on the page. I already have reference of css file on the "order.aspx" page.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/query/jquery-ui-themes-1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
 <script language="javascript" src="/query/jquery-2.1.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script language="javascript" src="/query/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Since I declare the dialog box on the user control of the user bar like that  `<div id="dialog-box"></div>,` I don't need to declare it again on the order page. If I declare it, then it cause a problem.

I have searched the web and tried many way to close the dialog box but none is work. Would some one help me. Thanks.

There is my jquery of the dialog box

```
function openDailogBox(url, name, width, height) {  
$('#dialog-box').load(url).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: true,
    height: height
    width: width,       
    title: name,
    modal: true,
   draggable: false

});
   $('#dialog-box').dialog('open');
    return false;
 }

function CloseDialogBox() {   
  $('#dialog-box').dialog({
   autoOpen: false,
   resizable: true,     
   title: name,
   modal: true,
  });

   $('#dialog-box').dialog('close');   

 }
```

There is the button to close the dialog with problem. It is same as the button on the menu bar's user control without difference id.

```
  <input class="btn" id="btnCancelOrder" type="button" value="Cancel" />
  $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#btnCancelorder').click(function (e) {
             e.preventDefault();                 
             CloseDialogBox();
         });
     });
```

Even I recreated another jquery script to have dialog id in parameter and on the order page the new dialog box with new id created. The issue is same, the title bar didn't disapper. Would someone tell me what I should do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: well ids need to be unique so having two items with the same id is not going to work. And if you are going to close a dialog, why would you create/initialize one?

Comment: could you recreate the problem in a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Chanckjh, I tried to create difference id using a new jquerry script, but the issue is same.